# PHPTAL and specific table

Tags: html-table, template-tal, phptal

I have to create specific table in PHPTAL.
I have array like that:

```
$tab = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4');
```

Final table should be look like that:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Item1</td>
        <td>Item2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item3</td>
        <td>Item4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I was trying use tal:condition width "repeat/item/odd" and "repeat/item/even" to fit < tr > tag in right place, but it not working that I want to.

Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr tal:repeat="row php:array_chunk(tab, 2)">
```